# opencv - Combine 3 channels into 1 by adding R+G+B

Tags: opencv

In OpenCV, is there a simple way to convert a BGR image into a sigle channel image, where each pixel is the sum of the B, G and R?

For example the following matrix:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6],
  [10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]
]
```

convert to:

```
[
  [6], [15],
  [60], [150]
]
```

I know I can use `split` on the 3 channels image and then add all three but wondered if there is something more straight forward.
thx

[EDIT]

What I am trying to do is compute the structure tensor of the image, as described in [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2313-433X/3/2/16). The structure tensor is defined as:
[image: 1]
where Lx, ax and bx are the sobel derivatives per the L, a, b channels

My current implementation (if I understood the paper correctly):

```
// Load and convert to Lab (keeping the raw lab values by using 32F matrix)
Mat lab;
img.convertTo(lab, CV_32F, 1 / 255.0);
cvtColor(lab, lab, COLOR_BGR2Lab);

// Compute derivatives in both directions 
Mat dx, dy;
Sobel(lab, dx, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3);
Sobel(lab, dy, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3);

// Now need to convert dx to single channel by adding L^2 + a^2 + b^2
Mat dx2;
multiply(dx, dx, dx2);
vector<Mat> dx2Cnls;
split(dx2, dx2Cnls);
Mat E = dx2Cnls[0] /* Lx^2 */ + dx2Cnls[1] /* ax^2 */ + dx2Cnls[2] /* bx^2 */;

// Do the same for dy
Mat dy2;
multiply(dy, dy, dy2);
vector<Mat> dy2Cnls;
split(dy2, dy2Cnls);
Mat G = dy2Cnls[0] /* Ly^2 */ + dy2Cnls[1] /* ay^2 */ + dy2Cnls[2] /* by^2 */;

// And now the cross dx * dy
Mat dxdy;
multiply(dx, dy, dxdy);
vector<Mat> dxdyCnls;
split(dxdy, dxdyCnls);
Mat F = dxdyCnls[0] /* LxLy */ + dxdyCnls[1] /* axay */ + dxdyCnls[2] /* bxby */;
```

Any way to avoid the `split` in order to combine the 3 channels?

Comment: are you using python or c++? Just adding them is not a good thing, this numbers are usually 8 bit values (0-255) and if you add one value of 200 with another one of 100 then it is 200 which will overflow or in the best case, it will change the cv::Mat/numpy array type to a type that allows such numbers (int/float/etc) What are you aiming adding the 3 channels together?

Comment: @api55 Thx, I will elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've calculated the derivatives, further processing handles each pixel position independently. That means we can take advantage of the in-memory layout of the pixel data, and [`cv::reshape`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4eb96e3251417fa88b78e2abd6cfd7d8) it to a more convenient shape.

We can turn `dx` and `dy` into 1-channel `Mat`s, with 3 columns (and width*height rows) -- each original pixel is on a new row, first column corresponds to `L` channel, second to `a` and third to `b`. Reshaping is an O(1) operation, so the cost of this is negligible.

The per-element multiplication will still work in the same manner (although we can use a [matrix expression](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#MatrixExpressions) instead of [`multiply`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga979d898a58d7f61c53003e162e7ad89f) to make things more terse).

We can then use [`cv::reduce`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4b78072a303f29d9031d56e5638da78e) to get per-row (i.e. per-pixel) sums.

Finally, reshape `E`, `F`, and `G` back to the original width/height.

---

**Sample Code**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Make some random data
    cv::Mat img(16, 16, CV_8UC3);
    cv::randu(img, 0, 256);

    // Load and convert to Lab (keeping the raw lab values by using 32F matrix)
    cv::Mat lab;
    img.convertTo(lab, CV_32F, 1 / 255.0);
    cv::cvtColor(lab, lab, cv::COLOR_BGR2Lab);

    // Compute derivatives in both directions 
    cv::Mat dx, dy;
    cv::Sobel(lab, dx, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3);
    cv::Sobel(lab, dy, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3);

    // Reshape the arrays to 1-channel, such that each original pixel is on
    // one row, first column is L, second is a, third is b
    // NB: This is O(1) operation.
    int new_row_count(lab.rows * lab.cols);
    dx = dx.reshape(1, new_row_count);
    dy = dy.reshape(1, new_row_count);

    // Get per-row (i.e. per pixel) sums for dx*dx, dx*dy, and dy*dy
    cv::Mat E, F, G;
    cv::reduce(dx.mul(dx), E, 1, cv::REDUCE_SUM);
    cv::reduce(dx.mul(dy), F, 1, cv::REDUCE_SUM);
    cv::reduce(dy.mul(dy), G, 1, cv::REDUCE_SUM);

    // Return back to original shape (but now only single channel)
    E = E.reshape(1, lab.rows);
    F = F.reshape(1, lab.rows);
    G = G.reshape(1, lab.rows);

    return 0;
}
```

---

In case we're after performance, there are still some opportunities left.

Specifically, if we calculate `E[r,c]`, `F[r,c]`, and `G[r,c]` at the same time:

- We can avoid allocating the temporary `Mat`s to hold the products of the derivatives (e.g. `dx.mul(dx)` -- even though we don't store the result of the matrix expression in a variable, it still allocates a temporary `Mat` to pass to `reduce`).
- We can make the algorithm more cache-friendly -- we read each `dx[r,c]` and `dy[r,c]` only once, and avoid storing the products to memory as well as retrieving them again (by which time they might have been evicted from cache(s)).

To allow processing with discontinuous output arrays (not very likely, but the cost is minimal), we will iterate with two loops. Outer loop will iterate over rows, and for each row will retrieve all the necessary input and output pointers. The inner loop will iterate over columns, and calculate `E[r,c]`, `F[r,c]`, and `G[r,c]` from `dx[r,c]` and `dy[r,c]`.

If we look at the formula...

```
E = Lx^2 + ax^2 + bx^2

E[r,c] = dx[r,c,0] * dx[r,c,0] + dx[r,c,1] * dx[r,c,1] + dx[r,c,2] * dx[r,c,2]
```

we can see that this is basically a [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition):

```
E[r,c] = dx[r,c] · dx[r,c]
```

Therefore we can use `cv::Vec3f::dot` to calculate the result elegantly.

The resulting implementation needs approximately 40% less time than the approach using `reshape` and `reduce`.

**Sample Code**

---

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void structure_tensor(cv::Mat const& img, cv::Mat& E, cv::Mat& F, cv::Mat& G)
{
    // Load and convert to Lab (keeping the raw lab values by using 32F matrix)
    cv::Mat lab;
    img.convertTo(lab, CV_32F, 1 / 255.0);
    cv::cvtColor(lab, lab, cv::COLOR_BGR2Lab);

    // Compute derivatives in both directions 
    cv::Mat dx, dy;
    cv::Sobel(lab, dx, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3);
    cv::Sobel(lab, dy, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3);

    E.create(lab.size(), CV_32FC1);
    F.create(lab.size(), CV_32FC1);
    G.create(lab.size(), CV_32FC1);

    for (int r(0); r < lab.rows; ++r) {
        cv::Vec3f const* idx = dx.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(r);
        cv::Vec3f const* idy = dy.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(r);
        float* iE = E.ptr<float>(r);
        float* iF = F.ptr<float>(r);
        float* iG = G.ptr<float>(r);

        for (int c(0); c < lab.cols; ++c, ++idx, ++idy) {
            *iE++ = idx->dot(*idx);
            *iF++ = idx->dot(*idy);
            *iG++ = idy->dot(*idy);
        }

        /* Or like this, pick what you like more.
        for (int c(0); c < lab.cols; ++c) {
            iE[c] = idx[c].dot(idx[c]);
            iF[c] = idx[c].dot(idy[c]);
            iG[c] = idy[c].dot(idy[c]);
        }
        */
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Make some random data
    cv::Mat img(16, 16, CV_8UC3);
    cv::randu(img, 0, 256);

    cv::Mat E, F, G;

    structure_tensor(img, E, F, G);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1797294 I've added a second, more optimized alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, learned new stuff... The reshape/reduce/reshape method is quite clever, although I understand the second is more efficient....

Answer (score 1):

For C++ you can use forEach member:

```
cv::Mat img1(200, 200, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(10, 50, 150));
cv::Mat img2(img1.size(), CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
img2.forEach<float>([&](float& pix, const int position[])
{
    cv::Vec3b p = img1.at<cv::Vec3b>(position[1], position[0]);
    pix = p[0] + p[1] + p[2];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I hoped for something with less code and more "readable"...

Comment: @user1797294 this has literally 3 lines of code and it's very elegant, about the readability it's just C++ instead of C-ish